# Autocompletion of usernames when replying to comments on mobile website (Chrome Android)

Tags: feature-request, comments, stack-snippets, mobile-web

When replying to a comment on desktop, one can write `@Fir` and have an autocompletion of usernames in the discussion that begin by `Fir`. Then we can either do TAB or click on the suggested username to have the autocompletion. This is not available on mobile Stack Overflow website. Thus, it's often difficult to answer to people: one has to write manually the sometimes-difficult-to-spell usernames (especially on a mobile phone keyboard).

**Can we enable username autocompletion box (clickable to accept autocompletion, like on desktop) on mobile?**

[image]

Comment: I don't think you could call it a bug unless there was some document saying that the mobile version was supposed to include these. The reason why there exists a mobile version is because it has to be a little different from the desktop version in order to function properly on a mobile device, and so some features are left out. I do like the idea of adding the autocomplete for names, but these are just features that you are requesting, not bugs.